# Capistrano: Supply password from local variable for ssh sign-in so that there is no prompt

Tags: ssh, capistrano, capistrano3, sshkit

I was wondering if it is possible to use an asked password for the ssh login, the `interaction_handler` doesn't seem to work for this task. So far I have:

```
ask :ip, 'Enter the ip of the server: '
fetch(:ip)
ask :pw, 'Enter user password: ', echo: false
fetch(:pw)

on "user@" + fetch(:ip) do
  execute "echo 'Hi.'", interaction_handler: {"user@#{fetch(:ip)}'s password" => "#{fetch(:pw)}\n"}
end
```

On that execute line, it tries to log into the server and the server prompts for the password. How can I supply it with the one stored in `:pw`?

Comment: In general you should be using SSH keys and SSH-Agent rather than passwords for this. A totally unhelpful answer, but just in case you hadn't considered this as an option. I don't know how you could do what you are trying to do, although I imagine that there is a way. Good luck!

Comment: @will_in_wi I had considered this, but I really want this to happen before any of this setup happens. (so when you only have root or the user and havent set up these other options). Thanks for the good wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be in https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md

```
host = SSHKit::Host.new('user@example.com')
host.password = "hackme"

on host do |host|
  puts capture(:echo, "I don't care about security!")
end
```